# Complex Pandas selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Col1  Col2    Col3  Value 
A      1      a         1  
A      1      b         1.4       
A      2      a         1.2
A      2      b         0       
B      1      a         1.2
B      1      b         0.5       
B      2      a         1
B      2      b         1.9
```

I want to select the row in the dataframe such that if I group by Col1 and Col2 and then average Value over Col3, I will keep the rows with the value of Col2 that corresponds to the min of the grouped dataframe. If I were to write it manually, in this case it would be

```
df[((df.Col1==A)& (df.Col2==2)|((df.Col1==B)&(df.Col2==1))
```

but it feels like there should be a way to do this directly and to handle more complicated cases (more unique values in Col1, Col2 etc..). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the columns to be grouped by as index, and use `idxmin`:

```
cols = ['Col1','Col2']

df = df.set_index(cols)

(df.loc[df.groupby(cols)['Value'].idxmin()]
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
Col1  Col2 Col3  Value
0    A     1    a    1.0
1    A     1    b    1.4
2    A     2    a    1.2
3    A     2    b    0.0
4    B     1    a    1.2
5    B     1    b    0.5
6    B     2    a    1.0
7    B     2    b    1.9
```